# jScroll pane responsive layout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

Hope someone can help...

Currently, I am using jScrollpane to handle the custom scrollbars for my project.

The layout is responsive and the content that populates the divs are dynamically generated. Everything is coming in fine with the exception of some clunky behavior when I resize my browser. I am using autoReintialise to watch for any changes  height and width. Again - working fine for the most part.

My issue is that when I drag the browser window and the widths of the divs expand, it appears any div with jScroll applied to it lags pretty badly. There is a slight delay and then catches up with the width of the div as it resizes - it's not really fluid at all.

My code sits inside a function inside the javascript file that handles the dynamic content. It's pretty much a direct copy form the example from the jScrollpane site:

```
function jscroll_refresh() {

var settings = {
    autoReinitialise: true
};
var pane = $(".scroll-pane");
pane.each(
function()
{
    $(this).jScrollPane(settings);

     var api = pane.data('jsp');
            var throttleTimeout;
            $(window).bind(
                'resize',
                function()
                {
                    if (!throttleTimeout) {
                        throttleTimeout = setTimeout(
                            function()
                            {
                                api.reinitialise();
                                throttleTimeout =null;

                            }
                        );
                    }
                }
            );
    });
}
```

Anyone else come across this issue? Other suggestions for a plugin like jScroll? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Found it!

It was something in the css for jScrollpane and not the javascript.

```
.scroll-pane{width: 100% !important;height: 93%;overflow: auto;}
.jspContainer{overflow:hidden;position:relative;height:100% !important; width: 100%      !important;}
.jspPane{position:absolute;width: 100%!important;}
```

I think jScroll was trying to constantly calculate the width on resize in pixels - this is forcing the percentages and thus giving me a smooth resize of the pane container.No more lagging.